# Field extension if element fixed by only identity

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Suppose that $E$ is a Galois extension of $F$ and that $α \in E$ is left fixed by only the identity
in $\text{Gal}(E/F)$. Prove that $E = F (α)$.

Please suggest how I should proceed. Thanks!

Comment: It often helps to identify some related goals for the problem.  For example:  Can we show that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$?  Can we show $E$ is a splitting field for the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$?

Answer (score 3):

Since the extension is Galois, the fundamental theorem of the Galois theory says that there exists a bijection between subfields of $E$ and subgroups of $Gal(E/F)$ by the correspondence which sends $H\subset Gal(E/F)$ to $E^H$.

The subgroup $H$ such that $F(\alpha)=E^H$ is the trivial group $\{1\}$ here thus $E=F(\alpha)$.